# DBForge can't connect with MySQL server, server is running

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, connections

I recently installed the latest version of MySQL Server.

I initialized it with --initialize-insecure so I have a "root" user with no password set.

The server is running, with the command `mysqld --console` I am able to start it.

I can connect to it through MySQL workbench just fine, port 3306, user "root", password not set

However if I try to use DBForge v7.2.34 the connection is refused, how can I solve this or at least debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research I figured out that it was a problem of user authentication, I had only a user 'root@localhost'. Turns out I needed an user 'root'@'127.0.0.1'

After all of that, I discovered my version of DBforge does not support MySQL server v8.0